# ListView Grouping by Column Value

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, grouping

ListView like this

```
Name    |    IP        |  Port
--------------------------------
Alice   | 192.168.0.1  |  1000
Bob     | 192.168.0.1  |  1000
Carol   | 192.168.0.1  |  1000
Dave    | 192.168.0.2  |  2000
Eve     | 192.168.0.2  |  2000
```

I want grouping by IP like {Alice, Bob, Carol} and {Dave, Eve}

If it `System.Collections.Generic.List`, I use `FindAll`.

But it is `ListViewItemCollection`, How can I grouping?

The way I can think of is to create a new List  by for loop with `ListViewItemCollection`.

Is there any other way?

Comment: You can group the data first, then bind it to list view or other control

Comment: Try following : listView1.Controls.Cast<ListViewItem>().GroupBy(x => x.SubItems[1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group the [ListViewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem?view=netcore-3.1) objects in a [ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview?view=netcore-3.1) control:

1. Group the [SubItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems?view=netcore-3.1) of a given [ColumnHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.columnheader?view=netcore-3.1).
2. Create a new [ListViewGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewgroup?view=netcore-3.1) for each group key and,
3. Assign it to the [Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.group?view=netcore-3.1) property of the grouped [ListViewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem?view=netcore-3.1) objects.

Create a *grouping* method to apply that:

```cs
private void GroupListViewItems(int columnIndex)
{
    if (!listView1.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>()
        .Select(c => c.Index).Contains(columnIndex))
        return;

    listView1.BeginUpdate();
    listView1.Groups.Clear();

    var groups = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
        .GroupBy(x => x.SubItems[columnIndex].Text);

    foreach(var group in groups.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
    {
        var g = new ListViewGroup(group.Key);

        listView1.Groups.Add(g);
        group.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Group = g);
    }

    listView1.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Width = -2);
    listView1.EndUpdate();
}
```

... and maybe an overload to pass the columns by their names:

```cs
private void GroupListViewItems(string columnName)
{
    var columnHeader = listView1.Columns.Cast<ColumnHeader>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.ToLower().Equals(columnName.ToLower()));

    if (columnHeader != null)
        GroupListViewItems(columnHeader.Index);
}
```

... call the method and pass the name/index of a [ColumnHeader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.columnheader?view=netcore-3.1). To *ungroup* the items, just clear the [ListView.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.groups?view=netcore-3.1) property.

[image: SOQ61998298]